# Generalized Euler's Formula for number of pieces?

Tags: graph-theory, induction, solution-verification

I am trying to generalize Euler's formula ($f+v-e=2$) for multiple pieces (pieces meaning different parts with no edges connecting the parts). I decided to do induction on the number of pieces, base case $ \text{number of pieces }= 1$ for which Euler's formula can be used. Then for the induction step I plan on assuming the theorem $f+v-e=k+1$ for $k=\text{number of pieces }$. I wanted to say it works for $\text{number of pieces } < k$ and then try to prove it works for $ \text{number of pieces } = k$. Then I treat each piece as an individual graph and do math (which I don't want to leave to the public internet) to say $f+v-e=2k-k+1$, which is obviously $k+1$. Then I wanted to add an edge, which obviously decreases the number of components, and rebalance the equation. I planned on saying that it is impossible to have a $k=0$ case this way because I acknowledged a $k=1$.  Is this a valid proof or did I fall into some invalid induction (induction trap)?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean. Do you mean generalizing, for example, to a disjoint union of $k$ polyhedra? In this case, it might be instructive to work out the case of $2$ tetrahedra.

Comment: I mean in 2-D Graphs. Did I describe the definition of pieces badly?

Comment: What are "2-D Graphs"? Euler's formula applies to polyhedra, which we usually visualize in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: I think this article explains it decently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs

Comment: @Travis It also applies to planar graphs, but you have to take care.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I see, that's sense of "graph" that OP means---the use of the term "2-D" is perhaps misleading here... Anyway, the section of the Wikipedia article actually contains a rough outline of a proof.

Comment: So it does! But that proof is for 3-dimensional solids.